# Controller method doesn't load with custom component and email template

Tags: email, controller, visualforce-component, email-template

I develop an email template which calls a Visualforce component with a custom controller (controller of the custom component).

I give an opportunity Id to my custom component and I would like load data (opportunity related lists) in the custom controller but it doesn't work.

I manage to forward the opportunity Id to the custom component which assign to a controller variable but in my controller, the variable is null..

This is the email template :

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Quote Support" recipientType="Contact" relatedToType="Opportunity">

<messaging:htmlEmailBody >

    <c:C01_SendEmailOpportunitySupport oppId="{!relatedTo.Id}" />

</messaging:htmlEmailBody>
```

The Visualforce component :

```
<apex:component controller="CC01_SendEmailOpportunitySupport" access="global">

<apex:attribute name="oppId" type="Id" description="Id of the opportunity" assignTo="{!opportunityId}"/>

...

</apex:component>
```

The custom controller :

```
public class CC01_SendEmailOpportunitySupport{

    public Id opportunityId{get;set;}
    public Opportunity theOpportunity{get; set;}
    public String theDate{get; set;}
    private DateTime theNow;
    public OpportunityContactRole theOpportunityContactRole{get; set;}

    public CC01_SendEmailOpportunitySupport(){
        System.debug('*** parameters : ' + ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('oppId'));

        init();
    }

    public void init(){
        System.debug('*** opportunityId : ' + opportunityId);

        this.theOpportunity = this.getTheOpportunityById(this.opportunityId);
        System.debug('*** theOpportunity : ' + theOpportunity );

        this.theOpportunityContactRole= this.getThePrimaryContact(this.opportunityId);
        System.debug('*** theOpportunityContactRole: ' + theOpportunityContactRole);

        this.theNow = DateTime.now();
        this.TheDate = this.theNow.day() + '/' + this.theNow.month() + '/' + this.theNow.year() + ' ' + this.theNow.hour() + ':' + this.theNow.minute();
    }
}
```

I guess the custom controller is loaded before the variable is assigned.

Please, someone can say to me how I I can assign the variable opportunityId?

Comment: How is the emailtemplate invoked? From apex or from a workflow/process?  You may not have the Opportunity in context which is why `OpportunityId` is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Component's controller initialization is bit different to normal controllers/ extensions. In case of a component controller. As I've observed, the setters are invoked before constructor. So, you should be able to tweak your code like this:-

Component

```
<apex:component controller="CC01_SendEmailOpportunitySupport" access="global">

<apex:attribute name="oppId" type="Id" description="Id of the opportunity" assignTo="{!opportunityId}"/>

{!LoadData}
...

</apex:component>
```

Controller:

```
public class CC01_SendEmailOpportunitySupport{

    public Id opportunityId{get;set;}
    public Opportunity theOpportunity{get; set;}
    public String theDate{get; set;}
    private DateTime theNow;
    public OpportunityContactRole theOpportunityContactRole{get; set;}

    public string getLoadData(){

        init();
        return '';//dummy return string
    }

    public void init(){
        System.debug('*** opportunityId : ' + opportunityId);

        this.theOpportunity = this.getTheOpportunityById(this.opportunityId);
        System.debug('*** theOpportunity : ' + theOpportunity );

        this.theOpportunityContactRole= this.getThePrimaryContact(this.opportunityId);
        System.debug('*** theOpportunityContactRole: ' + theOpportunityContactRole);

        this.theNow = DateTime.now();
        this.TheDate = this.theNow.day() + '/' + this.theNow.month() + '/' + this.theNow.year() + ' ' + this.theNow.hour() + ':' + this.theNow.minute();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple test : On your Visual for component add a line that says

hello opportunity Id : {!opportunityId}

```
<apex:component controller="CC01_SendEmailOpportunitySupport" access="global">
<apex:attribute name="oppId" type="Id" description="Id of the opportunity" assignTo="{!opportunityId}"/>
hello opportunity Id is : {!opportunityId}
</apex:component>
```

Go back to your template and click on Send Test and Verify Merge Fields, pick a user, pick an oppty and you should see a html preview as below

**hello opportunity Id is : 006d0000005z1IZAAY**

Comment: this is a good idea but it assumes that the Opportunity is in fact the relatedTo object when the email template is rendered by SFDC. If the template comes out of apex, the `whatId`'s SObject becomes relevant; similarly if the template is associated to a workflow/process, the object in context had better be an Opportunity

Comment: @crop1645 On the email template when the OP has declared the relatedToType="Opportunity" how do you say it could be any other Id?

Comment: I've had issues in past wherein context didn't exist to the expected sobject type when the email template was invoked - depends on how the template is invoked

Comment: @crop1645 When you try to use the VF template, the email template you choose on a WF is filtered based on the related to object, so we can rule out WF causing issues. Coming to sending email through an apex class, yes I do agree that setting a wrong whatId may screw up, but not sure how since I have not tested this route